# Import all elements of particular type from module

Tags: python, types, import, python-import, python-importlib

I want to import objects in a module that are only of particular types.

For example, the module to be imported is:

```python
# foo.py

a = A() # type(a) = A
b = B() # type(b) = B
```

Now I want to import elements of type `A` from `foo` (i.e. `a`).

Obviously, you could import all of `foo` then iterate through it to check types. I don't think that that is ideal, though.

Perhaps there is something in `importlib` that can facilitate this?

#### Edit

(Adding more information about use case.)

Basically, I'm trying to create something like [IPython magics](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/custommagics.html) and want to create a facility for custom magics.

The user is going to register functions in a file with a decorator, which will return an instance of the particular type.

Then, the user will pass the module's path on instantiation.

```python
# user_file.py

# decorator returns object of particular type (e.g. `foo`)
@register
def a():
  ...

def b():
  ...
```

Then something like this happens:

```python
# importing_file.py

class GetsRegisteredKeys:

  def __init__(self, paths:list):
    for path in paths:
      # import the elements that were registered, i.e. that have `foo` type.

grk = GetsRegisteredKeys(paths=['./user_file.py'])
```

The user won't actually call `GetsRegisteredKeys`. They just pass in the path somewhere else.

Alternative designs that avoid this sort of import altogether are welcome.

Comment: There is nothing of that sort in Python. And for a good reason. The fact that you are trying to do this suggests that there is probably something wrong with your design (although I cannot say more about it, because of the limited information)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do this, just put it into a function in itself and call it like that
(I think this is what you're trying to do, correct me if its not)

```
def A():
    return(a)

def B():
    return(b)
```

Then in your other python file do

```
import foo
a = foo.A()
b = foo.B()
```

foo obviously being the placeholder for the actual name of it.

Comment: I see how this could work in some cases. Unfortunately, it won't work in mine. I've added some more information in the edited version of the question.